# How to change One template to another in magento

Tags: magento, templates, product

In My Magento Website Product View is Currently using

`'frontend/base/default/template/qquoteadv/catalog/product/view.phtml'` template file.

How can I change it to use

`'frontend/default/sm_parna/catalog/product/view.phtml'` this path template

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing,

move `qquoteadv/catalog/product/view.phtml` to your theme under `frontend/default/sm_parna/` and merge the changes of `catalog/product/view.phtml'` file to `qquoteadv/catalog/product/view.phtml` .

This should be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you only wanted to change this file you have to edit catalog.xml file and point it to use your new file instead of the old one.
if you are changing the whole theme then you have to go to the admin configuration and in the design section change the theme to your own theme